# No DestinationFactory was found for the namespace - create uber JAR of CXF with Jetty

Tags: maven, cxf, embedded-jetty, uberjar

I want to create an uber JAR for a CXF-based application server. I want to run the server from the commandline with `java -jar`. In the IDE, I can run the main class `com.connexta.desertcodecamp.Server`, but I am not correctly creating the uber jar.

When I run the command `java -jar server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, I get

```
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:215)
        at com.connexta.desertcodecamp.Server.<init>(Server.java:19)
        at com.connexta.desertcodecamp.Server.main(Server.java:33)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No DestinationFactory was found for the namespace http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http.
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.DestinationFactoryManagerImpl.getDestinationFactory(DestinationFactoryManagerImpl.java:122)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:79)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:63)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:170)
```

Here is a link to the POM file (and GitHub repo):
https://github.com/ahoffer/desert-code-camp/blob/master/server/pom.xml

Other posts reference a missing dependency, `cxf-rt-transports-http`, but I have that as a dependency in the POM.xml.

Comment: are you sure you have it in the combined jar? _How_ did you combine the jars?

Comment: @bmargulies I don't know enough to answer the question. I don't know what combining means in this case. I included cxf-rt-transports-http as a maven dependency.  I assumed all dependencies would make their way into the shaded JAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was here: [apache camel - packaging an executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274151/apache-camel-packaging-an-executable-jar)
and here: [Missing cxf.xml? Fails in maven, works in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616339/missing-cxf-xml-fails-in-maven-works-in-eclipse).

Adding this transformer and magic resource to the configuration section of the maven shade plugin fixes it:

```
<transformer org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt</resource>
</transformer>
```

The resource is generated by the plugin; it is not necessary to create it